# Custom codesniffer rules / sniffs

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I'm looking for custom rules extending the PSR2 standard for CodeSniffer, but could not find a reliable solution.

Here is a sample code:

```
if ($var1==$var2) {
    $var3=1;
    $var4 = array("test"=>"test1");
}
```

I need to enforce spaces around the `==` `>=` `<=` and `!=` as well as when assigning variables `$var3 = 1;` and `=>` as well.

I have created a custom standard named `MyStandard` which extends PSR-2, where I have put rules for the cyclomatic complexity, line lengths and tab indents instead of spaces, but can't solve those last ones.

Edit: My current ruleset.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyStandard">
    <description>PSR2 with tabs instead of spaces.</description>
    <arg name="tab-width" value="4"/>
    <rule ref="PSR2">
        <exclude name="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowTabIndent"/>
        <exclude name="PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MissingNamespace"/>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowSpaceIndent"/>
    <rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent">
        <properties>
            <property name="indent" value="4"/>
            <property name="tabIndent" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </rule>
    <rule ref="Generic.Files.LineLength">
        <properties>
            <property name="lineLimit" value="140"/>
            <property name="absoluteLineLimit" value="160"/>
        </properties>
     </rule>
     <rule ref="Squiz.WhiteSpace.SuperfluousWhitespace">
         <properties>
             <property name="ignoreBlankLines" value="false"/>
         </properties>
     </rule>
     <rule ref="Squiz.WhiteSpace.SuperfluousWhitespace.StartFile">
         <severity>10</severity>
     </rule>
     <rule ref="Squiz.WhiteSpace.SuperfluousWhitespace.EndFile">
         <severity>10</severity>
     </rule>
     <rule ref="Generic.Metrics.CyclomaticComplexity"/>
</ruleset>
```

Comment: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/CodeSniffer/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/Strings/ConcatenationSpacingSniff.php might be a starting point for spacing around a concatenation operator

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you! It seems that something is overriding this sniff. I'm currently just pasting the code into the `MyStandard/Sniffs/MyStandard_ConcatenationSpacingSniff.php` with the approriate class name and no visible changes appears...

Comment: I have figured it out, thanks to @MarkBaker. I've used the proposed sample and modified it to check for `T_EQUAL, T_IS_NOT_EQUAL, T_IS_EQUAL,T_DOUBLE_ARROW, T_IS_IDENTICAL, T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL, T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL, T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL`. Can you provide your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, thanks to **@MarkBaker**.

I've used the proposed [sample](https://github.com/gamegos/php-code-sniffer/blob/master/src/Gamegos/Sniffs/Strings/ConcatenationSpacingSniff.php) and modified it to check for `T_EQUAL`, `T_IS_NOT_EQUAL`, `T_IS_EQUAL`, `T_DOUBLE_ARROW`, `T_IS_IDENTICAL`, `T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL`, `T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL` and `T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL`

If anyone is interested, here is the [complete ruleset](https://github.com/StanSoftBG/PSR2).

Comment: Hey Stanimir, I'm glad you found the solution. Could you mark it as an accepted answer? It would help others to see there is a solution in question overview.

Comment: Thanks @TomášVotruba

Comment: You're welcome. In case you'd like to know more about CodingStandard, check this: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/03/combine-power-of-php-code-sniffer-and-php-cs-fixer-in-3-lines/

Comment: Broken link in answer

Comment: Thanks @ScottAnderson . I've find the same file and updated the answer with a valid link for 2020.